# Bash Script execute command as user

Tags: bash, scripting, password, parameter

I'm just wondering if it's possible to execute a command inside a bash script as a specified user and supply the password in one string.

At the moment I have

```
COMMAND="${DIRECTORY}/script.sh"

su -c postgres $COMMAND
```

But this is asking me for a password which I won't be able to enter all the time as this script is going to be running in a cron every hour

Comment: Run it as root or use expect

Answer (score 1):

Several possibilities:

**sudo**

If you can configure it in a way that is both secure and flexible enough for your calls then you can use `sudo` to allow the script user to run the commands as user `postgres` without being asked for a password.

**sudo with wrapper script**

You can write a wrapper script which is writable by `postgres` or `root` only and checks that the call (script parameters) is correct. `sudo` can allow the script user to call the wrapper script with random parameters as `postgres`.

**SSH**

If there was only one command line to be executed then you could use SSH. You can bind a certain key to a command i.e. this key cannot be used for anything else.

Answer (score -1):

We can use pipe for applying password and I have used it and it work perfectly well.

COMMAND="${DIRECTORY}/script.sh"

su -c postgres $COMMAND | passwd "enter your password here"